# GridBag Layout half the components invisible

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to create a 3 by 4 grid  of jpanels. [2 by 4 is doable with gridLayout but i cannot add the cyan jpanel along the bottom.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0VDF.png)  [This is What I am getting when I use GridBagLayout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vk0j.png)
Bellow is my grid bag constraints I'm not sure why but panel 4-8 are invisible

```
     ///////////Build Top Panels///////////
    buildPanel();
    gc.weightx = 0.5;
    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    this.add(p1,gc); // panel1

    buildPanel2();
    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    this.add(p2,gc); //panel2

    buildPanel3();
    gc.gridx = 2;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    this.add(p3,gc);//panel3

    buildPanel4();
    gc.gridx = 3;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    this.add(p4,gc);//panel4

    buildBottomPanel();
    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 2;
    this.add(b1,gc);//panel5

    buildBottomPanel2();
    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 2;
    this.add(b2,gc);//panel6

    buildBottomPanel3();
    gc.gridx = 2;
    gc.gridy = 2;
    this.add(b3,gc);//panel7

    buildBottomPanel4();
    gc.gridx = 3;
    gc.gridy = 2;
    this.add(b4,gc);//panel8

    buildFooter();
    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 2;
    gc.gridwidth = 4;
    gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    this.add(footer,gc);//panel9
```

Comment: It sounds like someone's preferred sizes are been calculated properly. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: There really isnt any way for me to post my runnable code without dumping my 350 lines of code everything is needed to be initialized and built

Comment: Well, without knowing, in principle, how those panels are built, the best you will get is guess work, which really discouraged

Comment: *"There really isnt any way for me to post my runnable code without dumping my 350 lines of code .."* If you can''t manage an MCVE, why waste our time? Voted to close 'no MCVE'.

Answer (score 1):

buildBottomPanel() through buildBottomPanel4() are placed at (0, 2) through (3,2)

```
gc.gridx = 0;
gc.gridy = 2;
this.add(b1,gc);//panel5

gc.gridx = 3;
gc.gridy = 2;
this.add(b4,gc);//panel8
```

And then your footer is placed over top of them:

```
buildFooter();
gc.gridx = 0;
gc.gridy = 2;
gc.gridwidth = 4;
gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
this.add(footer,gc);//panel9
```

Use `gc.gridy = 1` for the bottom panels.